# How to deploy files to an Azure instance?

Tags: azure, windows-hosting

I have an Orchard CMS test site running in Azure. I have some theme files I want to deploy to the site. How do I do that? I was made a co-admin using my live-ID by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends do you want a temporarily put something to the server or is the change something that needs to be there after some publishes new version to the Azure.

If remote desktop is enabled then you can put some css files temporarily there (those will disappear after publishing new version as there will be new instance of virtual machine). Also if you have multiple instances of virtual machines then you have to copy the files to each of them. I don't recommend this solution.

If you want changes to be always there then you need to add theme files to your project and publish a new version. There are lots of instructions how to publish new version to the Azure (for example [this one](http://debugmode.net/2011/10/22/publish-azure-project-using-windows-azure-sdk-1-5-publish-setting-wizard/)).

There might be some Orchard specific solutions that I am not aware of, these instructions are about Azure in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Orchard, but if you want deploy files to Azure instance you can use RDC to add those on server. But that's not the best way because if something wrong happen to you instance Azure automatically recreates new instance with fresh deployment package without your uploaded files.

Comment: RDC should not be used. That can't be automated, it's not durable, and it's not replicated across instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the dashboard, themes, then "Install a theme from your computer".  Unless I've missed something?

Ahh - disregard what I just said.  Looks like you have to do a build then upload. See the bottom of this page:  http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Deploying-Orchard-to-Windows-Azure